# Performance of Post-Aggregations in Apache Druid

Tags: druid

What are the performance trade-offs that I must consider when using post-aggregations as opposed to defining metrics in the ingestion spec when rollup is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it all depends on the result set.

When you do this at ingestion time, it will only take some time when the data is pushed into your druid cluster. Selecting data is just a matter of retrieving the data from the segments.

An post-aggregation will run through the result of your query and then "re-process" the result. So this will have some overhead. How much is hard to tell though.

When you need more speed, or want to reduce CPU, I would recommend doing the changes at ingestion time. However, the downside is that this takes extra disk space, as you store the result of your calculation as a new column.

If disk space is a problem, I guess you could better use post-aggregations.